# Entity Framework Core 2.1 How to OrderBy() and Distinct()

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I want to select distinct from my table to get list of years 
So I wrote the code:

```
return await _context.SdrSettingHistory
                .Where( x => x.StartDate != null)
                .OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
                .Select(x => x.StartDate.Value.Year)
                .Distinct()
                .ToListAsync();
```

But it returned not ordered year. it returned like [2014,2015,2013]
How I suppose to order the year ?

I tried to move OrderBy after Distinct() it produce error:

```
error CS1061: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'StartDate' and no accessible extension method 'StartDate' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Note:
I use ASP.NET with EF Core 2.1

Comment: I try that one, move OrderBy(x => x.StartDate) after Distinct() . but it produce error : error CS1061: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'StartDate' and no accessible extension method 'StartDate' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: it won't work but i got test with orderby(x => x) it works now. i just wonder what if i have selected 2 fields in the select() like name and year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Select` and `Distinct` operators are not guaranteed to preserve order on other data providers, such as SQL Server. You need to move your `OrderBy` operator after them. Since your projected value after the `Select` is an `int`, you can just order by it directly:

```
return await _context.SdrSettingHistory
    .Where(x => x.StartDate != null)
    .Select(x => x.StartDate.Value.Year)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .ToListAsync();
```